# How to initialize a custom model field for testing?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've got a custom model field `class VaultField(CharField):` which is used to store values in Vault.

Used like so:

```py
class MyClass:
  secret = VaultField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

The custom field is using `self.model.__name__`.

My plan was to unit test this field by initializing it and calling the methods (`from_db_value`, `to_python`, etc.):

```py
field = VaultField(blank=True)
field.to_python()
```

But because the field is using `self.model` it's erroring on:

```bash
AttributeError: 'VaultField' object has no attribute 'model'
```

How do I get a `model` into the `VaultField`?

This does not work:

```py
VaultField(max_length=200, blank=True, model=MyModel)
```

Comment: Just an ongoing thought but it seems MyClass does not inherit models.Model

Comment: What package does `VaultField` come from?